# Render output in Blender 2.8 shows different output than the viewport display

Tags: animation, render, viewport, blender, viewport3d

I am following a course from Udemy on blender 2.8 fundamentals. As the editing in the final animation was complete, I tried to render it, but the rendered output seems to be different from the viewport display.

In the render output, somehow all of my objects are being cut through by a plane. At first, I thought that it was the floor from my animation that was causing this issue. I tried to render again after making some changes to the floor, but I am still facing the same problem.

I have linked the viewport and render output screenshots below.

[Viewport Display #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juGFh.jpg)
[Render Output #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6i3V.jpg)

[Viewport Display #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQgyG.jpg)
[Render Output #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESq6h.jpg)

[Viewport Display #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65hN3.jpg)
[Render Output #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnbMy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no hidden object in the scene, it does not appear in your viewport, but in rendering everything will appear.  To fix it, just delete the hidden object, or disable it from being rendered, (there is a button for that).